# IllegalStateException when using drawable XML

Tags: android, drawable, illegalstateexception

When using an ImageButton with this XML:

and the following drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bruin_s1" android:state_pressed="false" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bruin_s2" android:state_pressed="true" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bruin_s1" android:state_focused="false" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bruin_s2" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

It will crash when I click that button with this exception:

```
06-17 10:18:23.028: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at nl.ivaldi.borre.Drawing.onColorClick(Drawing.java:135)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     ... 20 more
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable
06-17 10:18:23.048: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(290):     ... 24 more
```

However, when I change the drawable to one of the images (i.e. bruin_s1) it will work just fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility when you wil get both `state_pressed` and `state_focused` as true. In that case which image your selector will select to show?

**Try with the following**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedpressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" />
</selector>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: The first item in the selector that has its conditions met will be selected. Android doesn't evaluate all items if it finds one that matches. That it why the normal state drawable always goes at the end. Even in your example, there would be more than one item that matches (one + the last one).

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Drawing.onColorClick`

In your layout, you have a View with an `android:onClick='onColorClick'`, but that method doesn't exist.

Comment: No, that would cause a different error, namely: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onColorClick(View) in the activity
Also, it wouldn't matter if I change the drawable then.

Comment: The answer was based on your previous stack trace. I see you've worked passed that original problem and edited with a new stack trace. For your new exception, I would look at the code at nl.ivaldi.borre.Drawing.onColorClick(Drawing.java:135) and see what kind of casting is happening below that call. The stack trace doesn't show exactly where that exception occurred, but it's somewhere under there.

Answer (score 0):

The error was somewhere else in my code. In the onclick handler, I was getting the background of the pressed button, to get the color of a certain pixel, however, when using drawable xml's, this goes wrong apparently.